# Convert Array of [[Double]] to String (similar to Print() output)

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

`let intervals = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]`

I would like to store this intervals variables into `CloudKit` as String in the same form as a `print` output eg:

```
print(interval)
```

output = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]

How can this be achieved? All the solutions from SO and googling only led me to doing a join whereby the arrays would be lost eg: [1,1,2,2,3,3]

Comment: “ as String in the same form as a print output” don’t do that. Use a real serialization format like yaml or json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
let intervals = [[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]] 
let res = "[\(intervals.map { "[\($0.first!),\($0.last!)]" }.joined(separator: ","))]" 
print(res)
```

**OR**

```
let res =  String(data: try! JSONEncoder().encode(intervals), encoding: .utf8)!
```

**OR**

```
let res = String(describing: intervals)
```

Comment: Or `String(describing: intervals)`

Comment: @FabioFelici short good way added , despite i notice some spaces in between with it's log **[[1,1],[2,2],[3,3]]** against **[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]**